# How do you create a 16 bit heightmap from mapbox rgb terrain png using python

Tags: python, mapbox

The code below comes close to working but the output image whitest white actually turns black.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  In the example image the black part is the top of the mountain this should actually be white. In addition I am using the full range for normalization 65535 if I try to use 255 the image is all black.  I need to be able to use full 65535 and 255.

```
rgb_elevation = PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(images_array[key]))

rgb_data = np.array(rgb_elevation)
r = rgb_data[..., 0]
g = rgb_data[..., 1]
b = rgb_data[..., 2]
decoded_data = -10000 + ((r * 256 * 256 + g * 256 + b) * 0.1)

im = np.array(decoded_data)

im2 = ((im - im.min()) / (im.max() - im.min()) * 65535).astype(np.uint16)

outimage = Image.fromarray(im2)
outimage.save(save_path)
```

https://imgur.com/a/wbM4gWU

Comment: Please share your input image. In the meantime, try using `r = rgb_data[..., 0].astype(np.float32)` and likewise for `g` and `b`.

Comment: The imgur link above does not work?  I tried pasting it in as a link in the post but it would not take it. Let me try another way.

Comment: The link in your post is the output image, surely?

Comment: Yes, the file size is 5mb and stackoverflow won't let me add it as an attachment.  I am combining multiple images/tiles together to get a higher res.

Comment: Mark, thank you that fixed it.  Please put that as the answer and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your `np.uint8` types are overflowing, so suggest you promote them before scaling, with:

```
r = rgb_data[..., 0].astype(np.float32)
g = rgb_data[..., 1].astype(np.float32)
b = rgb_data[..., 2].astype(np.float32)
```